# Test coverage of Case and EmailMessage triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have created 2 triggers to save a custom field on Case - `Description_HTML__c` which should keep the HTML version of the Case Description.

The first trigger is:

```
trigger updateCaseDescription on Case (before update) {
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();
    map<Id,EmailMessage> mapEmailMessage = new map<Id,EmailMessage>();
    for(Case c:trigger.new){   
        parentIds.add(c.Id);
    }   
    list<EmailMessage> lste = [select id,HtmlBody,parentId from EmailMessage where parentid in:parentIds and Incoming = true];

    if(lste.size() > 0 ){
     for(EmailMessage e:lste){
         mapEmailMessage.put(e.parentId,e);
     }
     list<Case> lstC = new list<Case>();
     for(Case c:trigger.new){ 
      if(mapEmailMessage != null && mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id) != null)   
          c.Description_HTML__c = mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id).HtmlBody;       
     }
    }
}
```

And the test class is:

```
@isTest
private class updateCaseDescriptionTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Subject = 'Om Test';  
        c.Description_HTML__c = 'testing';
        EmailMessage b = new EmailMessage();
        b.HtmlBody = 'test';

        try
        {
            insert c;
        }
        catch(System.DMLException e)
        {
            System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('Record already exist with same email Id'));
        }
    }
}
```

My Code coverage yields 50%.  How can I improve that? (targeting 75%).

The second Trigger is destined to reveal the inline images in the 'Description_HTML__c' custom field, and is as follows:

```
trigger UpdateDescTrigger on EmailMessage (after insert,after update,before insert ,before update) {
    //set<id> CaseIds = new set<Id>();
    map<Id,EmailMessage> MapEmailMessage = new map<Id,EmailMessage>();
    List<Case> newList = new List<Case>();
    for(EmailMessage e:trigger.new){
        MapEmailMessage.put(e.ParentId,e);
    }

    list<Case> lstC = [select Id,Description_HTML__c from Case where id in:MapEmailMessage.keyset()];
    for(Case c:lstC){
        if(MapEmailMessage != null && MapEmailMessage.get(c.Id) != null )
            c.Description_HTML__c = MapEmailMessage.get(c.Id).HtmlBody;
            newList.add(c);
    }
    if(newList.size()>0)
    {
        update newList;
    }
}
```

For this second trigger I am unsure where to begin with the test class.

Comment: 1st test - are you inserting the EmailMessage recording? 2nd Test - Create a Case Record, then create and insert an EmailMessage where the ParentId = Case.Id. Plus lots of system asserts :)

Comment: A note - the assert in your catch will not prevent the test from succeeding if the catch never occurs.  I would save the exception's message to a String and place your assert outside of the try-catch block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for minimal code coverage of trigger1 and no code coverage of trigger2 is you are not inserting any test records for `EmailMessage`. Try this test class:

```
@isTest
private class updateCaseDescriptionTest {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        //Insert test case record
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Subject = 'Om Test';  
        c.Description_HTML__c = 'testing';
        Status ='New';
        Priority = 'Medium';
        Origin = 'Email';
        insert c;

        //Insert emailmessage for case
        EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage();
        email.FromAddress = 'test@abc.org';
        email.Incoming = True;
        email.ToAddress= 'test@xyz.org';
        email.Subject = 'Test email';
        email.HtmlBody = 'Test email body';
        email.ParentId = c.Id; 
        insert email;

        //Assert if case Description_HTML__c updated with emailmessage htmlbody value
        System.assertEquals([Select Id, Description_HTML__c From Case Where Id = :c.Id][0].Description_HTML__c,
                            'Test email body');
    }
}
```

If you need to assert any exception, try to insert a case record with field values that may cause exception.

Comment: Thanks Reshma. 
This test covers 100% of the trigger.
I'm facing a different issue now - this trigger is actually updating the 'Description_HTML__c' custom field of the Case object, on EVERY EmailMessage which arrives in the Case.  
Originally, I wanted to update the 'Description_HTML__c' only once, with the first incoming Email Message.  Any change you can further help me adjust the SOQL query to meet this functionality?

Comment: @iDog This is something different requirement than the question you posted. Please post it as a new one and accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help Reshman. Much Appreciated. 
I reported the additional issue as a new question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159730/trigger-to-copy-case-description-to-rich-text-custom-field-upon-first-incoming