# Trigger to copy Case Description to Rich Text custom field - upon first incoming EmailMessage

Tags: trigger, case, email2case, emailmessage

I have the below trigger on Case, which helps in copying the incoming EmailMessage to a custom field (of type Rich Text), so we can have an 'HTML' Case Description, rather then the out-of-the-box text converted field.

```
trigger updateCaseDescription on Case (before update) {
    set<Id> parentIds = new set<Id>();
    map<Id,EmailMessage> mapEmailMessage = new map<Id,EmailMessage>();
    for(Case c:trigger.new){   
        parentIds.add(c.Id);
    }   
    list<EmailMessage> lste = [select id,HtmlBody,parentId from EmailMessage where parentid in:parentIds and Incoming = true];

    if(lste.size() > 0 ){
     for(EmailMessage e:lste){
         mapEmailMessage.put(e.parentId,e);
     }
     list<Case> lstC = new list<Case>();
     for(Case c:trigger.new){ 
      if(mapEmailMessage != null && mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id) != null)   
          c.Description_HTML__c = mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id).HtmlBody;       
     }
    }
}
```

The trigger is actually setting the 'Description_HTML__c' custom field on EVERY incoming EmailMessage, which is not as desired. 
How can I limit this to perform only once - for the first Incoming EmailMessage?

Thank you.

Comment: You do realize `mapEmailMessage` *cannot* be null...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add another condition to your If statement...

```
if(mapEmailMessage != null && mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id) != null && parentIds.get(c.Id) == null)   {
      c.Description_HTML__c = mapEmailMessage.get(c.Id).HtmlBody;       
 }
```

That will inhibit any overwrites of that field from a new E-Mail. But, you will also have to change your set to a map..

```
map<Id, string> parentIds = new map<Id, string>();
map<Id,EmailMessage> mapEmailMessage = new map<Id,EmailMessage>();
for(Case c:trigger.new){   
    parentIds.put(c.Id, c.Description_HTML__c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks John. 
I added the condition as suggested, and after testing it seems to be working as expected.
I then noticed your edited comment, and I wonder if this will still work without changing the 'set' to 'map'.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of preparing `mapEmailMessage` map you can verify if parent Id already exists in the map or not. If not exists then only add the parent Id and corresponding `EmailMessage`.

```
for(EmailMessage e:lste){
    if(!mapEmailMessage.containsKey(e.parentId))
    {
       mapEmailMessage.put(e.parentId,e);
    }
}
```

Also, put suitable `ORDER BY` in SOQL

```
SELECT id,HtmlBody,parentId FROM EmailMessage 
WHERE parentid in:parentIds 
AND Incoming = true
ORDER By parentId
```